# Generate CMake compile commands on Windows

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm setting up a C/C++ build environment on Windows using Eclipse CDT, CMake and the cmake4eclipse plugin. Everything works fine except the generation of compile_commands.json. This file is required by the cmake4eclipse plugin in order to use the two CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS providers for automatic include detection etc. (as far as I understood that correctly).

I'm using Windows builds of CMake (3.20) and ninja as well as the MSYS2 version of gcc. All tools are accessible via the PATH variable (compilation works fine as I already mentioned).

My cmake command roughly looks like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=ON -G Ninja "C:\\path\\to\\source"
```

During configuration I always get the warning

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS
```

and no compile_commands.json is generated in the build directory.

I understand that this is often a problem when trying to export compile commands for generators which are not supported, e.g. Visual Studio. But since I'm using ninja, I would expect a successful generation of the JSON file.

Did anyone experience similar issues or has any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:
Here's the output with `message(STATUS "gen = ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")`:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=ON  -G Ninja "C:\\path\\to\\source" 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/usr/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- gen = Ninja
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS


-- Build files have been written to: C:/path/to/build
10:52:57 Buildscript generation finished (took 9351 ms)
```

Unfortunately I can't post my whole CMakeLists.txt since it belongs to a project in our company. The top-level CMakeLists.txt does not define any targets, but adds a couple of ExternalProjects to support cross-compilation.

Comment: I tried and failed to reproduce this using a minimal CMakeLists.txt. Can you try your same workflow with a basic CMakeLists.txt and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Minimal meaning "cmake_minimum_required + project + add_executable" with `int main() {return 0;}` in a source file.

Comment: Try `message(STATUS "gen = ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")` to make sure the generator is being set correctly.

Comment: Can you post the full output and your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Posted the full output including `message(STATUS "gen = ${CMAKE_GENERATOR}")` in my original post.

Comment: "The top-level CMakeLists.txt does not define any targets, but adds a couple of ExternalProjects to support cross-compilation." Does this mean your top-level CMakeLists.txt does not define any _compiled_ targets? If so, that would explain it. CMake settings do not propagate into ExternalProject steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error message with the following CMakeLists.txt. This is not a bug:

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test)
```

I then ran

```
> cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29915.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29915.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS


-- Build files have been written to: D:/test/build
```

The reason for this is because, as you say,

> The top-level CMakeLists.txt does not define any targets, but adds a couple of ExternalProjects to support cross-compilation.

The commands for custom targets are not included in the `compile_commands.json`, and the variable is only inspected by CMake when processing the first compiled target (either `add_executable` or `add_library`).

There is no simple fix; setting `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` in each of your sub-projects will result in one `compile_commands.json` file for each. Merging them such that Eclipse will understand the result is beyond the scope of this question.

This is part of a larger issue with `ExternalProject` -- it's *too* separated. It boils down to automating the creation of some relatively complicated custom targets and commands, so the parent project has no idea what's going on in its children.

A better approach for cross-compiling with host tools is to allow the user to call your build twice: first with a host toolchain in one directory and second with a target toolchain in a different directory with variables set so that the first build will be scanned for host tools instead of re-creating the targets in the target build. The `export()` and `find_package()` commands are useful for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex! I already thought that this warning is caused by the ExternalProject_Add() in my top-level CMakeLists.txt, but I wasn't able to rule out any tool-compatibility-related problems (since the build process runs on Windows) either.

Comment: I don't really like the ExternalProject approach (sometimes causing problems with unnecessary rebuilds). I think I'll try to get rid of this approach in the future...

Comment: One more question: Can you provide some resources about cross compiling with CMake without external projects? I don't really understand what you mean by building twice. Would this approach involve two separate 'top-level' CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I'm actually working on writing a blog post that explains the technique better... but for now here's a build I wrote for testing Halide that uses it: https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/master/test/integration/xc

Comment: The idea is to separate your host tools into a different directory and either add_subdirectory or find_package based on whether you're cross-compiling

Comment: Also, don't forget that inside the `CMakeList.txt`, you need to use the `$ENV{}` syntax for accessing the `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` env variable. I had a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724763/717355

Comment: @PhilipOakley - what does your comment have to do with my answer?

Comment: @AlexReinking, Assuming I understood the core element of the question about "automatic include detection" implying that there was no extra command line parameters (e.g. VS/Ninja using Open Folder running the CMakeList.txt) then in my case I needed to detect if the env variable had been defined (for use cases with command line), and then set the env variable (this case) so that the export was actioned for this same cmake run. I had assumed that you would be able to get the CMakeLists.txt updated if the right logic was available.

Comment: setting `ENV{CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS}` has zero effect on `ExternalProject`. Setting `ENV{CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS}` after `project()` has been called does _nothing whatsoever_.